# Rust for loop countdown using range operator does not work

Tags: rust

Rust for loop countdown using range operator does not work
When I try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64db4d364a7b6c5f5c16be82b7f0e852)

```
for i in 1..9 {println!("{}",i)}
```

I got

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Which is to be expected
But when I try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccd9a6ee3dc209c253e583ef5261a01b)

```
 for i in 9..1 {println!("{}",i)}
```

I got nothing

I'm expecting to see something like this

```
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Question

1. Why does it not work
2. How to count down using for loop in Rust

Comment: `i in (1..9).rev()`

Comment: Yes. But not very satisfying.
Why does it design this way?

Comment: Changing it now is a breaking change anyway, so impossible. But I guess perf considerations.

Comment: @Kyrielight it was designed this way because when the starting and end points are variables, not literals, it's more easy to think that if the end is smaller than the beginning, it won't do anything, rather than suddenly going the other way around. This greatly simplifies many things. For instance, if you wanted to insert a range in a segment tree, you would expect to insert the empty interval if you inserted 1..0, not to insert a backward-going (whatever that could mean) interval. Besides, making it going the other direction is quite easy.

Comment: @Kyrielight makes sense I guess, but this should really be a compiler warning in this specific context. Or I guess more generally loops whose repetition count eagerly evaluates to zero should be. There are more than one ways to mess this up with an iterator in a really misleading way.

Comment: @LőrincBethlenfalvy [`clippy::reversed_empty_ranges`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#reversed_empty_ranges).